# Converting Nationality to Country in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a library to convert nationality to country name or country code in Python. A data set contains a column with artist name and nationality and I am trying to map them by country.

For example,

```
Danish = Denmark or DE
Italian = Italy or IT
Japanese = Japan or JP
American = USA or US
```

I have tried pycountry but it doesn't support nationality.
Are there any python libraries to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try importing a dictionary for Demonym's

> A demonym or gentilic is a word used for people or the inhabitants of a place

One like: [Demonym csv listing](https://github.com/knowitall/chunkedextractor/blob/master/src/main/resources/edu/knowitall/chunkedextractor/demonyms.csv)

And simply do a lookup. If you also want the country code, you need another mapping
[Country codes mapping](https://mledoze.github.io/countries/)

I'm not aware of a complete library for this already existing.

Comment: Thanks for Demonym csv listing. I could simply map it with Python